# Matplotlib regression scattered plot using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression

[image]

**My Question**

I tried regression using curve_fit function from scipy module, and now I am getting a scattered kind of plot, I can't figure it out, Why I am getting a scattered plot here ?

**My Code**

```
def scipyFunction(x,y):
    plot(x, y, 'o', label='Original data', markersize=10)

    x = [float(xn) for xn in x] #every element (xn) in x becomes a float
    y = [float(yn) for yn in y] #every element (yn) in y becomes a float
    x = np.array(x) #tranform data into numpy array
    y = np.array(y) #transform data into numpy array

    def functionForScipy(x,a,b,c,d):
        return a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d 

    #make the curve_fit
    popt,pcov = curve_fit(functionForScipy,x,y)

    '''
    The result is :
    popt[0] = a, popt[1] = b, popt[2] = d of the function,
    so f(x) = popt[0]*x**3 + popt[1]*x**2 + popt[2]*x + popt[3].
    '''

    print(popt)

    plt.plot(x, popt[0]*x**3 + popt[1]*x**2 + popt[2]*x + popt[3], label="Fitted Curve")  # same as lin eabove

    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
```

x and y plot is like this :

[image]

Comment: Are you asking why your green line is not straight but is instead jumping around the place?

Comment: How do `x` and `y` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this occurs because the values in your `x` array are not monotonically increasing (that is to say that the each subsequent number is larger than the last).

You need to sort your x values before you plot them otherwise they will be all over the place, as shown in the example below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x):
    return x**2

x = np.array([0, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4])
y = func(x)

plt.plot(x, y, 'b-', label='Unsorted')

x.sort()
y = func(x)

plt.plot(x, y, 'r-', label='Sorted')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `x` and `y` are not sorted.

**Don't forget the apply the same sorting you do on `x` on `y` as well**. To achieve this `zip` is very handy. You could add the following at the beginning of your function:

```
comb = zip(x,y)
comb.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])  #sort according to x
x, y = zip(*comb)  #both x and y are sorted now according to x
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just a minor mistake in here zip object cannot be sorted like that, it has to be converted into list, thus comb = list(zip(z,y)), and then apply sort..thanks anyway.. :)

Comment: @AkashRana run `print type(zip([1,2,3],[2,3,1]))` ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, from [python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip): `zip([iterable, ...])`

    This function returns a **list** of tuples.